# ASP.NET - A question about pages URL like: article200,view.html

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm wondering about that: as I've seen, many pages (possibly developed in ASP.NET) has (url rewriting ?) like http://abc.com/article200,view.html. Am I right? Is it form of URL Rewriting in ASP.NET ? If so, what's the difference between the .html and the .aspx page in that scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that they mapped the html extension to the ASP.NET isapi so that it gets handled as a .aspx page.

Grz, Kris.

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between the
>   .html and the .aspx page in that
>   scenario ?

None. Althought the page has html extension, it could be an ordinary aspx page, whose url has been rewrited to render the page with another extension. In this case, the extension is html, but could be anything else, or without any extension at all.

I guess that you could do this kind of url rewriting with ASP.NET 4, but be aware that the url that you give isn't very SEO friendly.